# new FormData works on one site but not on other

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my previous project I have:

```
let send = (form) => {
        form = $(form)
        ...........
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: new FormData(form[0]),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        ..........
        return false
    }
```

And my form looks like:

```
<?php $form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'w0',
                        'action' => 'site/send-contact',
                        'fieldConfig' => [
                            'options' => [
                                'tags' => false
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
................ some fields ............
\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Here, using the `new FormData(..)` works totally fine. You can check it [here](https://clothes.titdesign.com/en/contacts-8) in the console networks tab. I have added `var_dump($_POST)` in the action. Now on my new project, `new FormData(..)` doesn't work. Absolutely no idea why. The dumped array is empty.

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'site/index',
            data: {
                data: new FormData($("#w0")[0])
            },
        })
```

And the form:

```
$form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin();
........... some fields here ............
\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end()
```

Tried with `post`,`get`,`contentType`,`processData` just for any case but still empty array. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Blind shot here because I don't have sufficient information. Perhaps `$("#w0")[0]` is empty, instead it should be `$("#w0")`? What about just using `new FormData(form[0])`, which is the working example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form submit event to submit form using ajax:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $(".formclass").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // stopping submitting
            var data = $(this).serializeArray();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                if (response.data.success == true) {
                    alert("Wow you commented");
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });

        });
    });
```

[For more info](https://riptutorial.com/yii2/example/9995/submitting-ajax-form)